# In responsive theme ,after creating a block with two regions how to arrange it one below the other when the width is reduced?

Tags: css, html, drupal-7, responsive-design

Currently creating a single page responsive website in drupal 7 ,after making the page responsive ,added a block with two regions aboutus and ethics side by side that is in two column.
While reducing the browser width ,the content still remainas it is !!! I want the region about us to be below  ethics ,but i am not aware how to do!!
Can anyone guide me with the aforestated question.

Comment: `after making the page responsive` How did you do that? Did you use @media queries, and include the meta viewport element? Did you write @media rules for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use float:left on both elements and give them a fixed width.

When the page is reduced enough they will automatically stack.

Comment: Thank you for your warm response..even after using float:left on both elements and giving them fixed width the content aboutus and ethics are still remaining in same manner even after reducing width..Actually we added the content in two blocks through drupal admin interface..Can anyone has other option regarding this as how to make them appear one below the other while reducing the width?